# Cakefile build task crashes on error

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, build-automation

I've copied a few cake snippets from the internet and tried to automate the building of my project.

There are two versions of the build task. One uses exec:

```
{exec} = require 'child_process'
task 'build', 'Build project from src/*.coffee to lib/*.js', ->
  exec 'coffee --compile -m --output lib/client scripts/client/', (err, stdout, stderr) ->
    throw err if err
    console.log stdout + stderr

  exec 'coffee --compile -m --output lib/server scripts/server/', (err, stdout, stderr) ->
    throw err if err
    console.log stdout + stderr
```

and one uses spawn:

```
task "build2", "build and watch with spawn",->
    client = spawn "coffee", ["--compile", "--map", "--output", "lib/client", "scripts/client"]
    client.stdout.on "data", (data)->console.log data.toString().trim()

    server = spawn "coffee", ["--compile", "--map", "--output", "lib/server", "scripts/client"]
    server.stdout.on "data", (data)->console.log data.toString().trim()
```

I've manually compiled my project, started the server, checked that it worked and then executed the two tasks. They both returned without an error message.

Then I added one obviously wrong line to the client-side coffeescript, just something like "123/gff&&728709§""" and executed both tasks again:

- The task with exec crashes with the error message "throw err, Command failed"
- The task with spawn returned silently. It doesn't crash but neither does it record the error in my code

What is the right way to use cake for building coffeescript ? How can I fix my code ?

Comment: The first version seems to be working for me, if I add an invalid line, it throws something like `'throw err, Command failed: Error: In scripts/client/test.coffee, Parse error on line 4: Unexpected 'STRING'`, otherwise it compiles fine

Comment: My error message only tells me: "throw err; Error: Command failed: at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:540:15) at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17) at maybeClose (child_process.js:638:16) at Process._handle.onexit (child_process.js:680:5)"

Comment: I am using the version with ``exec``, but my experience is that on Windows, the error messages are not very clear. Haven't had time to investigate why. What does the compiler do when you try to compile the source file manually including the error you mention?

Comment: Manual compilation returns a useful error message: "game.coffee:4:32: error: unexpected IDENTIFIER sadlfiu3%773khgk"

Comment: Is this on Windows? Contents of stderr should be included in the error message of child_process.exec. The result you're getting suggests stderr may not be captured correctly, and the variable is instead entirely empty. In case of spawn, you should add `client.stderr.on "data", (data)->console.log data.toString().trim()`. There should be output on stderr if the coffee command fails.